# -= works different in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

When I use:

```
f = f - df
```

everything works.
Hence:

```
f-=df
```

results in this error:

```
UFuncTypeError: Cannot cast ufunc 'subtract' output from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') with casting rule 'same_kind'
```

Does the -= operator work any different in numpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `var3 = var1 - var2`, python constructs a new object var3 to which  casting rules are applied.

However, in the `var2 -= var 1` example, there are only two objects, hence the cast has to be explicit.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is what is happening here:

-= is an inplace operation for the mutable object `f`. The inplace operation does not work in this case, because it would change the datatype of `f`.